# How to write an HTML button which can run both onclick and onserverclick?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a HTML button which is connected to some external JS and on its onclick events my JavaScript functions would run. The functions consist of some alerts. Now I would like to write my main code which is in C# language but as soon as I write onserverclick event in my button, my onclick events don't work anymore.

My button code is:

```
<input runat="server" type="button" id="btn_submit" class="btn_submit" 
       value ="ثبت" onclick="mail_valid()" onserverclick="BtnRegister_Click"/>
```

How can I make both the "onclick" and "onserverclick" event handlers work?

Edit:
I want to avoid from postback in the button thats why i used html button .

Comment: If you want to fire an onServerClick event, you're going to need postback.

Answer (score 2):

Create a asp:button control:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnMyAction" OnClick="server event handler" OnClientClick="string" />
```

for more information read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i want to avoid to auto post back for button thats why i used html button .

Comment: @Arashbahreini so you want something to happen on server but not do a postback or page load? if so, you need to user ajax.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Page_Load` method, you can use `btn_submit.Attributes.Add("onClick","mail_valid()")` to add the JS function to the button.